# Classification of a finite group $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Can we classify a finite $G$ with the given condition: for non-identity elements $x, y \in \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p \leq G$ with $ \langle x \rangle \neq \langle y \rangle$, we have $ \langle g_1x g_1^{-1} \rangle = \langle g_2yg_2^{-1} \rangle$ for some $g_1, g_2 \in G$? Here $\mathbb Z_p$ is a cyclic group of prime order.

I have noted the following observations:

- $Z(G)$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ if $G$ satisfies the above property;
- non cyclic abelian group does not satisfy the above property;
- symmetric group $S_n$ does not satisfy the above property.
- if every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is either cyclic or generalized quaternion group (for $p= 2$), then $G$ satisfies the above properties.

Also, I have searched lots on Google  but did not find any clue. I am so thankful for providing any literature or any classification regarding the problem.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The holomorph of $\mathbb Z/p\times\mathbb Z/p$ is an example.

Comment: Here's a good example: $G=A_5$, $p=2$.

Comment: @Shaun I have some observation, $Z(G)$ is cyclic if $G$ satisfies the above condition. Also, I know some example which contains a subgroup $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ but it does not satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly. (Not everyone checks the comments.)

Comment: Thanks Kenta and Kabenyuk for providing the example. I try to move further by considering these examples.

Comment: Moreover,  If a group $H$ satisfies the condition, then it holds for any group $G>H$.

Comment: Ah, it has occurred to me that the OP wants that condition to hold for all elementary subgroups of $G$ that are isomorphic to $C_p^2$ for some prime $p$. With that condition, some kind of classification seems feasible.

Comment: The groups ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ (for $p$ prime) have the property.

Comment: @DerekHolt, you are right, this group satisfies that property.

Comment: @kabenyuk That isn't true. It is true that the statement holds for elements of $H$ in $G$, but $G\setminus H$ could introduce more elements where it fails. For example, the property holds for $C_2$ and $C_2$ but not for $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, thank you for noticing my comment. But all I was saying was that if a group $H$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$, in which all subgroups of order $p$ are conjugate in $H$, then the same is true for any group $G$ containing $H$ as a subgroup.

Comment: On the other hand, if OP considers a slightly different property, namely, if two elements of group $H$ of order $p$ commutate then the subgroups generated by them are conjugate in $H$, then of course I am wrong. The special linear group $SL(2,q)$, where $q = 2^s$, $s >2$, satisfies this last property for $p=2$.

Comment: @kabenyuk I assumed the OP's statement was that the property holds for all such pairs. Because if that is not the case, then $S_n$ is almost always an example, not a non-example.

Comment: @David you are right,  my requirement is $G$  should be satisfied this property for all prime $p$, $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p \leq G$ and for all such pairs. Thanks every one for giving your valuable time and comments.

Comment: @Struggler Oh, then I think it makes sense to clarify your question. 
Can your property be formulated like this?
If $x,y\in G$ are commuting elements of the same prime order, then the subgroups $\langle x\rangle$, $\langle y\rangle$ are conjugate in $G$.

Comment: @Kabenyuk ok, I try to formulate this one.